# Marginal from conditional given no parameter reliance

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If $Y|X \sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$ is it true that $Y \sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$. This intuitively seems true as the Normal is characterized by the mean and variance, which have no reliance on $X$. So no matter what realization of $X$, the distribution of $Y$ stays the same, however I am not satisfied with this intuition and was looking for something more detailed.

Edit:
I believe this works:
\begin{align*}
p_Y(y) &= \int_{x} p_{Y|X}(y|x) p_X(x) dx\\
&= p_{Y|X}(y|x) \int_{x} p_X(x) dx\\
&= p_{Y|X}(y|x)
\end{align*}
and so $Y \sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$.

Comment: @whuber I mean to say that conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is Normal(0,1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

\begin{align*}
p_Y(y) &= \int_{x} p_{Y|X}(y|x) p_X(x) dx\\
&= \int_{x} \phi (y) p_X(x) dx\\
&= \phi (y)\int_{x} p_X(x) dx\\
&=  \phi (y)
\end{align*}

where $\phi(y)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac {y^2}2}$ is pdf of standard normal distribution.